# Free/affordable bibliographic research

Tags: publications, research-process

I have some medical device ideas and I want some basic bibliographic research to assess feasibility and novelty. Is there a free or affordable service that can do this?

Comment: the librarian at the library of a university with a full medical program can probably help you. You may need some association with the institution, however.

Comment: You may also need to research patents in the area.

Comment: By "bibliographic research", do you mean that you want to find and read relevant papers and books?  Or that you want to do research on bibliometrics?

Answer (score 1):

In the medical (and medical devices) field, [pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) is the place to go and the search is free. In most cases the abstracts should give enough hints on whether a paper might be relevant or not.

You should check patent databases (just ask google about "free patent search") as well.